Contextvars not working in Azure Durable Function and FastAPI
I'm having a problem using FastAPI and Azure Durable Function.
I want to customize my logs using contextvars in my Azure Durable Function + FastAPI project but I'm encountering different problems.
The custom fields that I want to have in my logs seem to show, in some logs, the old value and when there are a lot of parallel requests, they show the values of other requests and not the ones that are related with their associate request.
How the Azure Durable Function + FastAPI project needs to be structured to customize logs using contextvars?
I handled this type of problem trying to use a method where I set the different value of the fields that I want to show in my customized logs and I call this method in each request; an example can be a POST request that then makes the orchestrator start and the orchestrator makes different parallel activities start (following the parallel pattern) and after they are finished, it calls another activity (with this it is following the fan-in/fan-out pattern) that updates the DB.
But what I see is that, when there are a lot of parallel requests, the fields in my customized logs are being overwritten by other requests and also, if I make another request start after one is finished I see the old fields value in my new customized logs.

sorry, we can´t guess how your code is now, and therefore can´t give any change suggestions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
